Using Flask to transmit RSTP streams works normally, but it fails to work after hosting Flask with Tornado
I created a webpage using Flask to stream RSTP video from a camera to the webpage.
rtspUrl = 'rtsp://user:password@10.238.1.1/h264/ch1/sub/av_stream'

def gen_frames():    
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(rtspUrl)    
    while True:        
        success, frame = camera.read()         
        if not success:
            pass
        else:            
            ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            frame = buffer.tobytes()
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')  

@app.route('/playvideo',methods=['GET'])
def playvideo():
    return Response(gen_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8082)

html code:
</div>
<img src="{{url_for('playvideo')}}"  width="100%">
</div>

When running Flask in debug mode, it works normally.I can open the webpage and the video plays normally.
import sys
import asyncio
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from ZYBpowercfg import app  #my flask project
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, Application

class CORSHandler(RequestHandler):
    def set_default_headers(self):
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*')
        
if sys.platform=='win32':
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
http_server=HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(8082)
IOLoop.instance().start()


However, after hosting Flask with Tornado, the webpage becomes inaccessible and stays in a continuous loading state.I suspect that Tornado is blocking the transmission of the stream.but I'm not sure where the problems.
i try to change the http header,but not ok

I seems Tornado is trying to get the entire response body before passing it on to the client.
have a look at @gen.coroutine or @web.asynchronous .
